# APC installation

Tags: zend-framework, xampp, apc

I'm trying to install APC on my mac.  I'm using XAMPP.  I ran this command from the /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin directory

```
sudo ./pecl install apc --alldeps
```

I got back a ton of errors.  There were several yes/no options which I just typed in what was suggested.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I could use some advice if there is any to give.  I'll post the entire installation log.

```
parsePackageName(): invalid package name "--alldeps" in "--alldeps"
invalid package name/package file "--alldeps"
downloading APC-3.1.9.tar ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.9.tar (Unknown size)
.................................................done: 801,792 bytes
54 source files, building
running: phpize-5.3.1
grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Enable internal debugging in APC [no] : no
Enable per request file info about files used from the APC cache [no] : no
Enable spin locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : no
Enable memory protection (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : no
Enable pthread mutexes (default) [yes] : yes
Enable pthread read/write locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : no
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9
running: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/configure --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=yes --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable APC support... yes, shared
checking whether we should enable cache request file info... no
checking whether we should use mmap... yes
checking whether we should use semaphore locking instead of fcntl... no
checking whether we should use pthread mutex locking... yes
pthread mutexs are supported!
checking whether we should use pthread read/write locking... no
checking whether the target compiler supports builtin atomics... yes
checking whether we should use spin locks... no
checking whether we should enable memory protection... no
checking for zend_set_lookup_function_hook... no
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for union semun... yes
checking whether we should enable valgrind support... checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
yes
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking for shm_open in -lrt... no
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from cc object... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
checking if cc static flag  works... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin11.2.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c -o apc.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:34:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:61:17: error: php.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:62:30: error: main/php_streams.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:34:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:69: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:70: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:71: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:72: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:73: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:74: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:77: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:78: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:79: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:80: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:83: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:84: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:85: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:92: error: 'MAXPATHLEN' undeclared here (not in a function)
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:93: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'php_stream_statbuf'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:96: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:99: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:100: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:107: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_zend.h:36,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:35:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:44:18: error: zend.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:45:22: error: zend_API.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:46:26: error: zend_compile.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:47:23: error: zend_hash.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:48:29: error: zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_php.h:66:21: error: rfc1867.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:35:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_zend.h:79: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_zend.h:80: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_zend.h:82: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_zend.h:83: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:34,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:37,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:49: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:50: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:51: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:52: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:53: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:54: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:55: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:81: error: expected ')' before 'limited'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:82: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sma.h:85: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'apc_sma_get_avail_size'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:37,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:63: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:65: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:66: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:77: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'apc_palloc_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:107: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:109: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:111: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pool.h:112: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:38,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:32: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:36: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'apc_serialize_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'apc_unserialize_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:38: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:56: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'apc_serialize_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:57: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'apc_unserialize_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:58: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:44: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:45: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:46: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:47: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:48: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:49: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:70: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'apc_serialize_t'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:76: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:77: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:51: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'zend_function'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:61: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'zend_class_entry'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:91: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:92: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:93: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:94: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:95: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:115: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:116: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:117: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:124: error: expected ')' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:129: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:130: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'apc_register_optimizer'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:135: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:136: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:141: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:142: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_lock.h:40,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:41,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:35: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:37: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:38: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:39: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:40: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_sem.h:41: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_lock.h:41,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:41,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_fcntl.h:35: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_fcntl.h:37: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_fcntl.h:38: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_fcntl.h:39: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_fcntl.h:40: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_lock.h:42,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:41,
                 from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.h:31: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.h:33: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.h:34: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.h:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'apc_pthreadmutex_nonblocking_lock'
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:44:18: error: TSRM.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:132: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'zend_op_array'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:140: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'zval'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:173: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:180: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:186: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:201: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:204: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:207: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:215: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:222: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:231: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:236: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:237: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:243: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:254: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:276: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:283: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'zend_op_array'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:287: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'TSRMLS_DC'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:290: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'apc_compile_cache_entry'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:296: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
```

**Update**
So I've made some more progress.  Turns out I needed to install a development package that took away most of the errors.  I'm running this command now:

```
sudo pecl install apc
```

Goes fine until the end then I get this...

```
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:393: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c: In function ‘apc_regex_compile_array’:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:454: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘preg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:454: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘preg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:455: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘nreg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:455: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘nreg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c: In function ‘apc_regex_match_array’:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:487: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘preg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:487: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘preg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:488: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘nreg’
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:488: error: ‘apc_regex’ has no member named ‘nreg’
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Now what?

Comment: There is actually more to the log, ran out of characters.  Last line was Error: 'make' failed

Answer (score 2):

You can use apc package if you are using any linux os

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

Reference : [Install APC on Linux(ubuntu)](http://www.codeweb.in/install-and-configure-apc-on-linux-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the major causes for errors is that the PHP header files seem to be missing or incomplete.

```
grep: .../php-5.3.1/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: .../php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: .../php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory

.../APC/apc.h:61:17: error: php.h: No such file or directory
.../APC/apc.h:62:30: error: main/php_streams.h: No such file or directory
```

I think the lack of the PHP header files is then causing the parse errors in the APC files because it doesn't have certain macro definitions.

You can try downloading the [PHP 5.3.1 Source](http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.1.tar.gz) and extracting all the .h files into `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/`  You will need to preserve the directory structure, because you at least need the header files from the `php` and `Zend` directory.

For some reason some of these files were deleted, are not where they are supposed to be or XAMPP didn't put them in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing *pcre-devel* using `sudo yum install pcre-devel` before installing *apc*.